# excel OnTime error when scheduled sub is run

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I am trying to get the Application.Ontime to work for one of my big subs but every time the timer runs out and it tries to run the sub i get an error that says:

[image]

macros are definitely enabled on the workbook im in. here is an example of my code that isnt working

```
Sub test()

    SchTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
    Application.OnTime SchTime, "transfer"

End Sub

Sub doot()

    'lets me know the sub started
    MsgBox "doot"
    Call test

End Sub
```

I can not for the life of me get it to work. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: copied it into a workbook (changed transfer to doot on the call) and it worked fine.

Comment: Is it running the sub transfer at all? Or does it error out on the first time? Transfer is the name of a subroutine in THAT workbook, correct?

Comment: @gtwebb the point of the sub is to run transfer() after the timer runs out, not just repeated show a txt box that says "doot"

Comment: @RyanWildry it doesnt run the transfer, it errors out first. and yes, I only have one workbook

Comment: where's the sub transfer? Do transfer has named parameters?

Comment: @Sgdva all of the subs are on the same sheet and what do you mean by named parameters?

Comment: 1. Does it have named parameters? IE: Sub transfer (Param1 as Variant) . 2. This may happen as well if transfer itself has unsolved errors for VBA.

Comment: oh, no transfer does not have named parameters, and when I run transfer() by itself it works perfectly

Comment: regardless of if i run transfer, i get the same error when i tell it to run doot after the timer runs out

Comment: try declaring SchTime as a date `Dim SchTime As Date`

Comment: @JerryT I still get the same error. it seems like something is messed up with the document settings based on the error but I cant figure it out. all the other subs run smoothly, idk why this one chooses to be picky

Comment: its because the code wasnt in a module, it was just stored on the sheet, i put it in a new module and it worked

Comment: I was just about to ask that.